# foreach inside while fetch array, the first output was doubled even though there are only 2 data in table

Tags: php, foreach

**This is my code**

```
        <?php 
            $album_id = $_GET['album'];
            $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT id,url from photos where album_id = '$album_id'");
            while($run = $query->fetch_array()){
                $urls[] = $run['url'];
                foreach($urls as $run){
                    $duh = $run;
                    echo '<a href="uploads/'.$duh.'" data-gallery><img src="uploads/'.$duh.'" style="width: 200px;"></a>';
                }
            }
       ?>
```

> i only have two data saved in database named **picOne.jpg** and **picTwo.jpg** but the output given is

### picOne.jpg

### picOne.jpg

### picTwo.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Fetch array only fetches one row at a time and $urls[] = $run['url'] is appending to the array $urls the url column of the row selected by fetch_array.

So, starting with the while loop, the first iteration you set the variable $urls to be array('picOne.jpg'). Then you enter the foreach loop and print each of the urls (there is only 1 thus far).  The second iteration of your while loop you ar taking the next row from the query result and appending to the existing array $urls and changing it from array('picOne.jpg') to array('picOne.jpg','picTwo.jpg') so when you reach the foreach loop, you now have two items to to echo to the screen.

Why do you have a loop within the loop?  Just remove the foreach loop and it should work fine.